# Trying to create a connection in Node.js using the npm light-orm and PostgreSQL (pg)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm

I am trying to create a postgreSQL connection using the light-orm.

I have it working in MySQL using:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    lightOrm = require('light-orm');

lightOrm.driver = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "me",
    password: "secret",
    database: "test"
});

lightOrm.driver.connect();
```

However I cannot seem to get it to work with PostgreSQL.

What I have is:

```
var pg = require('pg'),
    lightOrm = require('light-orm');

lightOrm.driver = new pg.Client('postgres://me:secret@localhost/test');

lightOrm.driver.connect();
```

I know that the connection is happening, because if I change the password to something incorrect, I get an error.  But when trying to use the same code that works with MySQL, I either get an error, or nada.

My guess is this problem stems from my lack of knowledge of the `pg` module and not a `light-orm` issue.

Comment: Try setting '?ssl=true' in your connection url

Comment: @asmodeus, same results.